# Query Builder in VS2010 using like and oracle

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to populate my DataGrid view with a query I am building in the Query Builder.
I ran this on Oracle SQL Developer and it works fine.  When I run it in Query Builder,
it gives me the error:  Error in Where Clause near '|'.  Unable to parse query text.
Error ORA-01008.  Any suggestions?    Thanks!

```
SELECT     LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, ADDR_1, ADDR_2, ADDR_3, CITY, STATE, ZIP_CODE           
FROM         ADDRESS_FIX
WHERE     (ZIP_CODE = :PARAM1) AND (ADDR_1 like (:PARAM2 || '%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the || entries in the query builder sql window after building and saving a query. Edit the sql and save. This will break the query builder but the dataset will be correct. Having this issue after moving to VS2015.

Comment: Could you give an example of what it should look like after editing?